# D3 bar chart from objects with arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

Good afternoon.

I am using this D3 bar chart example with my data (that is in the same format whereof in the 
jsfiddle example).

The chart works well but i have some problems that i do not know i solve.

1. The xAxis have the number of index of the key parameter and not the key parameters values;
2. When I sort the data after pressing the "sort" button;
3. The numbers over the bars after the sort disappear or appear the the left side insted of over the correspondent bars

`var dataset = {key: [0, 30], value:[60, 30]};`

http://jsfiddle.net/3HL4a/75/

Here is the link where you can see the code and perform the changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To reference the key values, you have to use those instead of the index:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(dataset.key)
    .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
// ...
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
  return xScale(dataset.key[i]);
})
```

You can make this nicer by merging the key and value arrays such that both are part of the same data element.

As for the other problem, this is because you're selecting `text` elements, which include the axis labels. Even with the key function this doesn't work here, as one of the axis labels is the same as the label you want to display on the bar. Assigning a special class to these labels and selecting accordingly fixes this.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3HL4a/87/) for the complete jsfiddle.

Comment: You can explaine me better how I can merge the key and value arrays?
And after this the way how I call the data is the same?

One more time thanks.

Comment: The data would look something like `[{key: 0, value: 30}]`. Then you would pass the entire thing to `.data()` and when computing the coordinates, pass `d.key` or `d.value` to the scale.

Comment: I change my data as o mention before although I can use this code 
var key = function(d) {
  return d.key;
};
I only have access to the d.value propertie of the data:
My data is a array of objects  [{}]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, but it might be better to put this into a separate question.